# Algoritmos Genéticos no Matlab

Tags: matlab

Estou precisando otimizar 30 funções no MatLab utilizando Algoritmos Genéticos.

Os dados iniciais são:

```
Dimensão=10
Rodadas = 51
Número Máximo de avaliações(MaxFES)= Dimensão*10000
Espaço de Busca=[-100,100]
Término=MaxFES ou o erro for menor que 10^(-8)
```

De cada função eu preciso obter o melhor e pior resultados, a mediana, a média, o desvio padrão e a taxa de sucesso (x/51)%.